# In a criminal trial, what is the sequence of proceedings?

Tags: england-and-wales, rules-of-court, criminal-procedure

Does the prosecution advance their own case first, calling their witnesses, examining them before the defense cross examines them, all before the defense then presents their case, calling each of their own witnesses to examine before they are cross examined by the prosecution?

Or can it depend on circumstances whether the prosecution presents their case first or the defense does. Can a party request for a different order of proceedings in a given case?

And does it matter who had coordinated and arranged for the attendance of a given witness who they may be called by? In other words, suppose the prosecution coordinated the preparation of and submitted the witness statements of witness A, B & C, the defence had arranged for the evidence statements of witnesses D & E, but all 5 of these witnesses’ statements are nonetheless admitted before the court.

Now suppose the prosecution is presenting their case first, as in the suggested standard sequence above, and it wishes to call witnesses D & E, even though these are not “their” witnesses. Is that allowed, to examine them of its own initiative prior to the defence having been given the chance to present their case? And suppose the prosecution has nothing to add to its own witness’s written statement through examination. Must the prosecution necessarily “call” its own witness?

If it doesn’t do so, then what impact does this have on the weight or admissibility of the written statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Jen is in general correct. Either side may call any witnesses who can give relevant information. It  does not matter who arranged for the witness to attend.  Usually the side which plans to call the witness makes arrangements. In some cases a side is bound by witnesses It has called. Each witness may be  cross examined before the next is called.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the sequence of proceedings?

See [Rule 25.9](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1107798/crim-proc-rules-2020-part-25.doc):

- the prosecution summarizes the case
- the defendant has an opportunity to concisely identify what the defendant intends to put into issue
- the prosecution introduces all of its evidence (including all of its witnesses) (and the defence has the opportunity to cross-examine each)
- the defendant has an opportunity to ask for a directed verdict of acquittal
- the defendant has an opportunity to summarize the defence case
- the defendant has an opportunity to introduce evidence, including witnesses (and the Crown has the opportunity to cross-examine each)
- either side may introduce additional evidence if needed in rebuttal
- prosecution's closing submissions
- defendant's closing submissions